# I dont seem to have the bisect tool

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools, knife-tool, bisect

[image]

I also checked the add-on list for the bisect tool figuring it was probably unincluded but found no add-on as well so I am confused.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Doesn't it appear if you keep pressed the button?

Comment: Try looking for it under the Mesh Menu (at the top of the 3D View) while in Edit Mode.

Answer (score 1):

It's there - You have to click on the icon and hold down the mouse button before you can select it. See below:

[image: Bisect]